# Could not parse the remainder: '():'

Tags: python, django

I got an error,

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /app/
Could not parse the remainder: '():' from 'json_dict.items():'.
```

I wanna embed json_parse method's result in  views.py  to index.html.
I wrote in views.py like

```
from django.shortcuts import render
    import json

    def index(request):
        return render(request, './index.html')

    def json_parse():
        f = open('./data/data.json', 'r')
        json_dict = json.load(f)
```

I wrote in index.html like

```
<html>
　<head>
　<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.2/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
　<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.css">
　</head>
　<body>
    <select id="mainDD" data-placeholder="Choose" class="chzn-select" style="width:600px;">
    {% for k, v in json_dict.items(): %}
        {% for i in range(len(k)) %}
            <p>{{ i }}</p>
            <p>{{ i }}</p>
            <p>{{ i }}</p>
            <p>{{ i }}</p>
            <p>{{ i }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

json_dict's  is  `{'items': [{'---': '---', ‘A’: ‘a’, ‘B’: ‘b’, ‘C: ‘c’, ‘D’: ‘d’}]}`.
I wanna embed ---&a&b&c&d  in this place of i variable of p tag.
I did not think Syntax Error happens in my codes, so I really cannot understand why this error happens.How should I fix this?What can I write it?

Comment: And if you delete the three characters it says it can’t parse? You don’t have a colon on the next loop, for example, so it’s not clear why you’d think you needed one in this one.

Comment: Of course, the next loop won't work either because `range(len(k))` isn't allowed. Not that you should ever be using that construct in any code anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `():` from templates

```
{% for k, v in json_dict.items %}
```